# How do I store an object in ArrayList?

Tags: java

I'm trying to store an object person in an ArrayList.

I have an `ArrayList<String> customer = new ArrayList<String>();`

The object 'person' has two variables: name (String) and pNr (long).
I have tried to simply add it: `customer.add(person)` but that doesn't seem to work.

To clarify: I don't want to store the variables individually. I want to store the entire object person in the ArrayList.

I simply can't figure out how to engage this problem or even if it can be done.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change your `List` such that it accepts a **Person object** instead of a `String`.

```
List<Person> customer = new ArrayList<Person>();
Person person = ......;
customer.add(person);
```

Answer (score 13):

Person Class

```
public class Person {       
    String name;
    long pNr;    

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getPNR() {
        return pNr;
    }

    public void setPNR(long pNr) {
        this.pNr = pNr;
    }   
}
```

Creating a Person Object

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("Name");
person.setPNR(pNr);
```

Adding to ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
personList.add(person);
```

Retrieving Data

```
String selectedName = personList.get(i).getName();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `List` with a different generic type.  Since the generic type specified on your current `List` is `String` it will only allow you to add objects of type `String` into the list.

```
List<Person> customer = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

I would also recommend using the `List` interface in case the need would arise to switch to a different implementation such as `LinkedList`.

Comment: ArrayList also retains order. Also, anything that implements List is required to retain some sort of order. (a PriorityQueue for example though, has a different way of specifying order)

Answer (score 3):

Look at this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tester4 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Tester");
        person.setPersonNr(1245L);
        persons.add(person);

        person = new Person();
        person.setName("Tester 2");
        person.setPersonNr(1299L);
        persons.add(person);
    }
}

class Person {

    private String name;

    private Long personNr;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getPersonNr() {
        return personNr;
    }

    public void setPersonNr(Long personNr) {
        this.personNr = personNr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<String> customer = new ArrayList<String>();
```

in this way you defined that the arrayList `customer` accept type `String` only.

```
ArrayList<Person> customer = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

this will only accept object with `Person` type (and subType of Person).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you insist on `ArrayList<String> customer`, then implement a `toString()` method in your Person class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person[name=" + name + ",pNr=" + pNr +"]";
}
```

Then you can use:

```
customer.add(person.toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

define a class Person

```
public class Person(){
    private String name;
    private long pNr;
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public long getPNR(){
        return pNr;
    }
    public void setPNR(long pNr){
        this.pNr = pNr;
    }
}
```

then you use a:

```
ArrayList<Person> customer = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to use `ArrayList<Person>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an object to an array list you would have to reference that object in the list type. IE: `ArrayList<Person> customer = new ArrayList<Person>();`