# How to store increment variable into array or stack

Tags: java, data-structures

I have an incremental variable and I want that to be stored into stack or array to print.

My code is like:

```
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < p; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if (stringVal[p].equals(stringVal2[j])) 
            counter++;                                           
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

What is happening, in this case, is that the counter is printed but it is printed separately. I want my output to be consolidated like the below. Therefore I want all the counter value to store in array or stack.

```
200
201
202
```

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: Do you want to store all the values that counter takes during the execution of that code?

Comment: Instead of print LINE `println` use another method like just `print` and then you won't get a bunch of new lines.

Comment: What google says when you ask it about arrays or stack in java?

Comment: @talex I knows how to print from stack and from arrays

Comment: @DavideSpataro yes exactly the same

Comment: @shankysingh take a look at this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648224/how-do-i-store-an-object-in-arraylist

Comment: @shankysingh so what is the problem? You don't know how to add to array. PS: I suggest you to use  `ArrayList` not array.

Comment: I just made an edit to address some typos and formatting in your post. I noticed that you said you wanted it to be "consolidated like the below" but in the markdown each number was on a separate line. If I made a mistake please [edit] your post to reflect the actual output you'd like.

Comment: What do you mean by printed separately?

Comment: I think you want to print on the same line? Then use System.out.print(counter+" ");

Comment: What do you like to do? What is the current output you are getting? Based on my understanding you need to store the value of the counter in an array or on the stack. You can do that by simply creating the desired data structure and copy the counter value in it. If you think there is a logical error, then please let us know the entire code. The value of stringVal and stingVal2?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing all the values of counter in a stack or array you can write the print code within the if condition like :

```
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < p; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if (stringVal[p].equals(stringVal2[j])) 
            System.out.println(counter++);                                           
        }

    }
}
```

The above method will save time and memory.